# variable scope problem in android

Tags: java, android

hi all
i have an arraylist and array in an activity and have two function. i declared arraylist and array in activity and used in a function. but i cannot access in those variables in second function. both function is in same activity. in second function gives NullPointerException in Logcat.
code:

```
public class testapplication extends Activity {
 ArrayList<String> getdatabase = new ArrayList<String>();
 public  String[] array;
 protected void onStart() {
      getdatabase.add("1");
      getdatabase.add("2");
      array=new String[getdatabase.size()];
      getdatabase.toArray(array);
      Log.e("app",""+array.length()); // print as app  2

   }

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 Log.e("app",""+array.length()); // NullPointerException.
 }

}
```

please help me.

Comment: Are you sure that onStart is running before onCreate?

Comment: According to Activity life cycle,onCreate is called before onStart, so you do the code in onCreate rather than onStart() and i want to know any particular reason for doing it in onStart()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onStart() is called after onCreate(), so array is not created yet. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStart%28%29).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that onCreate() is the method that is first called if your Activity starts. At this point, you haven't yet initialized your variable array. That's why you get a NullPointerException there.

To solve the problem you have to assure that you call this:

```
array=new String[getdatabase.size()];
```

before you try to access the array.

As coder_tim pointed out, in the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) you can clearly see that onCreate() is always called before onStart().

Comment: Agreed, check this out: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: Good link, there you can see that onStart is always called after onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing to Android activity life cycle, onCreate is called before onStart, that's why you got NullPointerException
Besides, just a heads up. You should call super.onCreate and super.onStart somewhere in the methods you overrided.